# Filter JSON in Angular 5+ with query

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

I have a question about displaying my result ngFor keeps complaining it is not an array. I tried to convert to a array but nothing helps.

My code:

```
searchQuery: any = {
user: {active: true},
cities: ['e991a8ee-e182-4ef7-82e2-142a3da4aec9', '2c01ea98-b545-4271-a69b-201962e4fb2f'],
ageGroup: ['3c7baa61-1e69-4c9b-9525-516c20cd4f56','56aa97f1-e51e-4347-8378-42569417c5a5'],
transportType: 0,
gender: 'c7122a10-d776-4789-859e-54b93fc26801'};
```

The search query can be empty if nothing is selected or if we want to search on transportType than the search query contains transportType. But can be more items if we want to search on that. 
From the server we receive a json array with a lot of objects. (+/- 15000 objects)

```
[{
        "id": "39d8c55a-e2d9-4ae5-b839-ff8aca4ec153",
        "user": {
            "active": false
        },
        "registered": {
            "status": 0,
            "date": "Tue May 01 2018 08:27:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
        },
        "cities": [{
                "id": "e991a8ee-e182-4ef7-82e2-142a3da4aec9",
                "label": "City A"
            }, {
                "id": "a4b20264-8038-405c-8ec0-8efcd0aa5f8f",
                "label": "City B"
            }, {
                "id": "e991a8ee-e182-4ef7-82e2-142a3da4aec9",
                "label": "City C"
            }
        ],
        "tasks": 10,
        "transportType": 2,
        "fullname": "John Doe",
        "gender": {
            "label": "male",
            "id": "c7122a10-d776-4789-859e-54b93fc26801"
        },
        "ageGroup": {
            "id": "3c7baa61-1e69-4c9b-9525-516c20cd4f56",
            "label": "27 t/m 34"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "c1597b80-9115-4ae6-a13c-06602a274e64",
        "user": {
            "active": true
        }
    }, {
        ....
    }
    ...etc]
```

The goal is to match de searchQuery agains the json from the server. So multiple results can be achieved.
In this example we want all users who are active and match all the city by uuid and the 2 ageGroups etc... (everything must match)
In my code there is a observable for the query and the server response and the filter result as a service in Angular.

```
@Injectable() export class SearchService {

  private searchQueryInit: any = {
    user: {active: true},
    cities: ['e991a8ee-e182-4ef7-82e2-142a3da4aec9', '2c01ea98-b545-4271-a69b-201962e4fb2f'],
    ageGroup: ['3c7baa61-1e69-4c9b-9525-516c20cd4f56','56aa97f1-e51e-4347-8378-42569417c5a5'],
    transportType: 0,
    gender: 'c7122a10-d776-4789-859e-54b93fc26801'   };

  private query: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(searchQueryInit);   private query$: Observable<any>;   readonly result$: Observable<any>;   private entities$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.AppState>) {
    store.dispatch(new storeActions.LoadEntities()); // call the store 
    this.entities$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllEntities); // load the entities
    this.query$ = this.query.asObservable().debounceTime(200);
    this.result$ = this.searchEntities();   }

  searchEntities(): Observable<any> {
     return this.query$.switchMap(
       (query) => {
         console.log(query);
         return entities$.pipe(
           mergeMap( (y: any) => y),
           filter((t: any) => t.transportType === 2), // refactor to multiple search items
        );
      }
     );   }

  get entities(): Observable<any> {
    return this.result$;   }

  set searchQuery(search: {field, query}) {
    // field: string, query: string
    const v = this.query.getValue();
    const next = (search.query) ? {...v, [search.field]: search.query} : {...v, [search.field]: null};
    this.query.next(next);   }

}
```

The searchQuery is not useful for this example but I put it here so you have the idea about how I build the query.

Maybe the whole setup is not the right way, so any advice is welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: So what do you want to iterate when it's complaining that it's not an array?

Comment: which fileds are you using in ngFor?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, iteration over a observable was not so good idea so I just filtered as a normal array and that solved my problem.

Comment: Thank all for your help and time